# Ошибка " 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, turtle

## Задача:

Нарисовать рисунок по тексту. Я пробовал все что мог. Пробовал на цикле While, пробовал изменить от цифра к строку, пытался ГУГЛИТЬ но все равно. Это не помогало мне. Помогите пж!

##################### - диапазон ошибки

ПРИМЕРЫ 'a' текста:

12345
21234
32123
43212
54321

12345
51234
45123
34512
23451

Это часть кода:

```py
weight = len(text[0])
heigh = len(text)
def circling(a):
    pen.pu()
    pen.goto(-weight // 2,-heigh//2)
    pen.pd()
    for i in range(1,heigh):
        for j in range(1,weight):
            print(text[i - 1][j - 1])
#########################################################################################
            a = abs(weight * i + j)
            if int(a[i][j]) == 1:
                pen.color("blue")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 2:
                pen.color("cyan")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 3:
                pen.color("green")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 4:
                pen.color("yellow")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 5:
                pen.color("orange")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 6:
                pen.color("red")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 7:
                pen.color("brown")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 8:
                pen.color("black")
############################################################################################
            pen.fd(10)
        pen.pu()
        pen.goto(0,j * 10)
        pen.pd()
```

Полный код:

```py
import turtle as tr
pen = tr.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.width(10)
tr.tracer(10)
text = [
"11111",
"11111",
"11211",
"11111",
"11111",
]

weight = len(text[0])
heigh = len(text)
def circling(a):
    pen.pu()
    pen.goto(-weight // 2,-heigh//2)
    pen.pd()
    for i in range(1,heigh):
        for j in range(1,weight):
            print(text[i - 1][j - 1])
            a = abs(weight * i + j)

            if int(a[i][j]) == 1:
                pen.color("blue")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 2:
                pen.color("cyan")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 3:
                pen.color("green")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 4:
                pen.color("yellow")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 5:
                pen.color("orange")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 6:
                pen.color("red")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 7:
                pen.color("brown")
            elif int(a[i][j]) == 8:
                pen.color("black")

            pen.fd(10)
        pen.pu()
        pen.goto(0,j * 10)
        pen.pd()
circling(text)
tr.mainloop()
```

Comment: а вы могли бы более точно описать задание

Comment: Задание таково: Изменить текст к рисунку. то есть 1 это синий, 2 это голубой, 3 это зеленый и т.д.
Но тут у меня не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот ваш код

```
for i in range(1,heigh):
    for j in range(1,weight):
        print(text[i - 1][j - 1])
        a = abs(weight * i + j)

        if int(a[i][j]) == 1:
```

в котором

```
a = abs(weight * i + j)
```

это число, а значит к нему нельзя обращаться как к списку, что выделаете в строчках ниже

```
if int(a[i][j]) == 1:
```

подозреваю, что в данном коде должна была использоваться переменная `text`

```
if int(text[i][j]) == 1:
```

Comment: Ёмаё, блин, где думал ошибка. Спс!!!

Comment: Приму ответ через 9 минут!

Comment: нет, после того как изменил код почти полностью я забыл удалить `a = abs(weight * i + j)` (Отвечаю на вопрос: подозреваю, что в данном коде должна была использоваться переменная text )